# Synchronize (Replicate) IMAP Messages

Tags: search, imap

I have an imap account, (e.g. some@gmail.com) and I know many libraries with which I can connect and replicate messages back to my destination. I want to achieve following,

1. First time, I want to download all messages (including sent folders), and when I download for the first time, I will save message with ID and UID locally in some database.
2. Second time, I do not want to query downloaded messages, even though their read/unread status or any flag or deleted flag is changed or they are purged.
3. Our aim is to download and sync every messages locally, once and only first time.

Now I know little about IMAP message that they have something called ID, UID and MessageID. ID is probably an offset in current folder, UID is numeric id in current account and MessageID is a unique string.

Now I want to know, what search I should use while querying folder, so that messages once downloaded, wont be returned back to me.

I am planning to use http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/ library, and it gives ability to Search with custom string and returns int array.

Assuming I have, a MaxID, and I want to only download messages which has ID or UID greater than MaxID. Which one should I use? UID or ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the UID in combination with UIDVALIDITY. Both values are folder specific.

There is an informational RFC that describes how IMAP clients should do synchronization ([RFC-4549](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4549), section 4.3). The text recommends issuing the following two commands:

```
tag1 UID FETCH <lastseenuid+1>:* <descriptors>
tag2 UID FETCH 1:<lastseenuid> FLAGS
```

The first command is used to fetch the required information for all unknown mails (without knowing how many mails there are). The second command is used to synchronize the flags for the already seen mails.

AFAIK this method is widely used. Therefore, many IMAP servers contain optimizations in order to provide this information quickly. Typically, the network bandwidth is the limiting factor.

Comment: Assuming two folders, inbox and spam, with 1000 and 100 as max UID in their folders. Now if in between two synchronization time, if message with UID 101 is received in spam and user moves it into inbox, what happens to the UID? does this message get new UID with 1001?

Comment: IMAP doesn't support move operations, instead emails have to be copied to the target folder and removed from the source folder. The UID is unique within a folder, and when an email is appended or copied to a folder, the email gets a UID that is greater than all previous UIDs used within this folder.

Comment: Also I found out about Search Since, will it be better off to sync on daily basis? I want to minimize server trips, why do I need to care for UIDVALIDITY?

Comment: There are many ways to sync IMAP clients, but I see no advantages in using `SEARCH SINCE`. Regarding UIDVALIDITY, there are several reasons why this is important: If the server has to renumber the emails (e.g. due to an overflow of UIDs), it will also change the UIDVALIDITY. If a folder is deleted and a new one created with the same name, the UIDs will start again with 1. The only way for a client to detect the change is the UIDVALIDITY, that will be different.

Comment: Can you please read and give me some hint on my this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803558/how-to-correctly-read-imap-fetch-response-with-body-size